# Why Line Clamp is not working with text align justify

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Why `-webkit-line-clamp` is not showing proper ellipsis with `text-align:justify`. It's working fine with `text-align:left/right`.

Please suggest any trick.

```css
div {
    text-align: justify;
    width:150px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 18px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>Why Line Clamp is not working with text align justify</div>
```

Comment: looks like a bug. are you seeing this in safari?

Comment: Nope, I am using Chrome

Comment: i would file this as a bug.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking why a certain browser may have an implementation bug that really should be a bug report.

Comment: What are you seeing that should or should not be happening? Define "not working".

Comment: ellipsis is not showing properly

Comment: @DanielA.White hmm good

Comment: I inspected the element with google chrome and changed its ' -webkit-box-orient: vertical;' to something else. It solved the issue. However, if you do it with JS it does not work.

Comment: Should `-webkit-line-clamp` be too buggy for reliable use, here are some alternative methods for applying ellipsis: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you're trying to use is a very old technique. It uses an old version of `display: flex;`, and should be avoided.

You can use the JavaScript technique, clamp.js, but I've also created this pure CSS version: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/meYKgZ?editors=110

**CSS**

```
p {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
}

p::after {
  content: "...";
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Of course this only works on a solid background, but most of the time that'll be the case with body text.

Here are the main points:

1. Set the line-height to whatever you like.
2. Set the height to a multiple of the line-height.
3. Set the overflow to hidden.
4. Add the ellipsis to the after pseudo-element and set its background color to that of the paragraph's background color.

Answer (score 4):

I solved with:

```
/* autoprefixer: off */
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
/* autoprefixer: on */
```

Comment: Solve by this, cause autoprefixer removed this css when enabled

Answer (score 3):

Webkit flexbox is half-baked and not standardized! I wouldn't say that this is a bug. Even Opera has it's own way to handle clamping, which is super annoying.

```
.last-line {
  height: 3.6em; /* exactly three lines */
  text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
}
```

You could use clamp.js to handle your ellipsis but if you're a fan of pure CSS solutions like me - try that:
[CSS Ellipsis: How to Manage Multi-Line Ellipsis in Pure CSS](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/je649tmd/)
I don't know why in your CSS it is not working, have changed some and did some Experiments, working for me. :)

**CSS:**

```
.line-clamp {
    text-align: justify;
    width : 155px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="line-clamp">Why Line Clamp is not working with text align justify</div>
```

Hope this will Work for you, or Help you to Solve your Issue.